# required attribute is not working. (html)

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I'm making a signup page using HTML and javaScript and it was working fine until I added a function to take the user to the next page, the problem is, if the textboxes where blank and I click on the button, it sends him to the next page instead of showing a validation error to fill them out.

here is the code of the function:

```
function signup() {
  window.location.replace("file:///C:/Users/hb/Desktop/web%20project/afterlogin.html");
  var userid = document.getElementById("username").value;
  alert("Welcome " + userid);
}
```

here is the html code for the form:

```html
<form method="post" class="info">
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" minlength="6" maxlength="18" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password" required> Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" minlength="10" maxlength="18" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="confirmpass">Confirm password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="confirmpass" minlength="10" maxlength="18" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <select id="gender">
      <option id="male"> Male </option>
      <option id="female"> Female </option>
    </select><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <select id="age">
      <option id="young">Young(12-18 years old) </option>
      <option id="youth">Youth(19-40 years old) </option>
      <option id="old">Old(more than 40 years) </option>
    </select><br /><br />
  </p>
  <div class="terms">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="terms" checked="checked" required />
      <label for="terms" id="terms">Agree to terms and conditions </label> <br />
    </p>
  </div>
  <button id="button" class="signUpButton" name="SIGN UP" type="submit" onclick="signup();">SIGN UP</button> <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <p class="outerAlt">Have an account already?</p>
  <p class="alt"><a href="">SIGN IN</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using ```window.location.replace("file:///C:/Users/hb/Desktop/web%20project/afterlogin.html");```.  Instead try using ```target="file:///C:/Users/hb/Desktop/web%20project/afterlogin.html"``` in the form element.    ```window.location.replace``` replaces the url of the browser tab!

Comment: Or make sure you add some if and else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for a click on the button, listen for the form submission event
eg:

```html
<form onsubmit="signup()">
```

Answer (score 0):

`required` attribute stops the form from submitting if the field is empty, it does not stop arbitrary event handlers from changing the page.
If you want to only call your `signup` when the form is valid make it a form submit handler instead of a button click handler.

```
<form method="post" class="info" onsubmit="signup();return false;">
...
    <button id="button" class="signUpButton" name="SIGN UP" type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` event will call the function when the button is clicked without validating the form. `onsubmit` event is called after the form is ready to submit (After the validation)

And you can use `event.preventDefault`(It will stop the page reloading after the submit. [More About it](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)) to instead of using `return false;`

```
function signup(event){
   event.preventDefault();
}
document.getElementById().addEventListener("submit", signup);
```

Add `addEventListener("submit", signup);` to call the function `onsubmit`

Ex: `document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", functionName);`

Ex 2:

```
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(){
   // Code
});
```

```js
function signup(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  location.replace("LOCATION");
  var userid = document.getElementById("username").value;
  alert("Welcome " + userid);
}
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", signup);
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form1" class="info" data-registerForm>
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" minlength="6" maxlength="18" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password" required> Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" minlength="10" maxlength="18" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="confirmpass">Confirm password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="confirmpass" minlength="10" maxlength="18" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <select id="gender">
      <option id="male"> Male </option>
      <option id="female"> Female </option>
    </select><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <select id="age">
      <option id="young">Young(12-18 years old) </option>
      <option id="youth">Youth(19-40 years old) </option>
      <option id="old">Old(more than 40 years) </option>
    </select><br /><br />
  </p>
  <div class="terms">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="terms" checked="checked" required />
      <label for="terms" id="terms">Agree to terms and conditions </label> <br />
    </p>
  </div>
  <button id="button" class="signUpButton" name="SIGN UP" type="submit">SIGN UP</button> <br /><br /><br /><br />
  <p class="outerAlt">Have an account already?</p>
  <p class="alt"><a href="">SIGN IN</a></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute required is activating when you submit the form. You can click on any button or input inside the form, call event `onclick`, but it won't be submiting the form. To handle the event of submiting, you have to add `onsubmit` to your `<form>` elements and on the code below. Note, that the form submit will reload the page. To avoid this, you have to prevent default behavior by adding `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
function signup(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var userid = document.getElementById("username").value;
  alert("Welcome " + userid);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="info" onsubmit="signup(event)">
  <p>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" minlength="6" maxlength="18" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required /><br /><br />
  </p>
  
  <button id="button" class="signUpButton" name="SIGN UP" type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```